# How to provide links to each data from many to many relationships on the admin site table

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Im newbie use python and django, I have problem in django admin site.

My plan is to give a different url to any existing data from many to many relationships that appear on the admin site table. When click data siswa will lead to the edit page.

```
# model.py
class WaliSiswa(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=TITLE)
    nama_lengkap = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    jenis_kelamin = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    relations = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RELATIONS)
    tempat_lahir = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tanggal_lahir = models.DateField()
    alamat_ktp = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    alamat_tinggal_saat_ini = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    profesi = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    nomer_telepon = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    nomer_seluler = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    siswa = models.ManyToManyField(Siswa)

# admin.py
class WaliSiswaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('getTitleNamaLengkap', 'relations', 'getSiswa', )

    def getSiswa(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([d.nama_lengkap for d in obj.siswa.all()])
    getSiswa.short_description = 'Siswa'
```

[image]

Like the picture above, I managed to display the data but confused to add its url. So I am very grateful for you who can provide the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django docs have you covered about how you can [`reverse` admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls).

Also, we'll need the pretty handy [`format_html_join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html_join) method.

```
# admin.py

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # django 1.9-
from django.urls import reverse  # django 1.10+
from django.utils.html import format_html_join

class WaliSiswaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('getTitleNamaLengkap', 'relations', 'getSiswa', )

    def getSiswa(self, obj):
        # Signature: format_html_join(sep, format_string, args_generator)
        return format_html_join(
               ', ', 
               '<a href="{}">{}</a>', 
               [(reverse('admin:<your_app_name>_siswa_change', args=(d.id,)), d.nama_lengkap) for d in obj.siswa.all()]
        )
    getSiswa.short_description = 'Siswa'
```

If you're using Python 3.6 then use f-strings (!):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # django 1.9-
from django.urls import reverse  # django 1.10+
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

class WaliSiswaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('getTitleNamaLengkap', 'relations', 'getSiswa', )

    def getSiswa(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            ', '.join([f'<a href="{reverse("admin:<your_app_name>_siswa_change", args=(d.id,))}">{d.nama_lengkap}</a>' for d in obj.siswa.all()])
        )
    getSiswa.short_description = 'Siswa'
```